# Making JList's selected index go away

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

So I have a JList in my program and it starts with the selected index 0. However, during the program I want to do myJList.setSelectedIndex(-1) or something like that so that nothing is selected ? Hope I was clear. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JList` has a method to clear the selection. See [`JList#clearSelection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#clearSelection%28%29). Check [`JList#getSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectionModel%28%29) and the [`ListSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) API to discover what methods are available to alter the selection

Edit: since you indicated it does not work, I created a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) showing the clearSelection works as expected

```
public class Test {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    try {
      SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
          frame.getContentPane().setLayout( new BorderLayout(  ) );
          DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
          listModel.addElement("Jane Doe");
          listModel.addElement("John Smith");
          listModel.addElement("Kathy Green");
          final JList list = new JList( listModel );
          list.setSelectedIndex( 0 );
          frame.getContentPane().add( list, BorderLayout.CENTER );
          JButton clearSelectionButton = new JButton( "Clear selection" );
          frame.getContentPane().add( clearSelectionButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

          clearSelectionButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent aActionEvent ) {
              list.clearSelection();
            }
          } );

          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible( true );
        }
      } );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
    } catch ( InvocationTargetException e ) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: My bad it works there was another bug. for some reason clearSelection does not work. Nothing happens when I call the method (at least in a visible way). the same list element still stays highlighted.

Comment: so my problem is that there is a valueChanged event for the list and I think clearSelection triggers it which leads to a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            jList.clearSelection();
        }
}
```

Another way:

```
    jButton1.addActionListener(
        (ActionListener)EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, jList1, "clearSelection"));
```

Comment: Yeah and I missed this method even I went through the list of methods one by one :) Thanks. Since Robin was first I will give him the check mark hope you dont mind (I am giving you an up though)